# python añadir amigo a otra lista

Tags: python, django

Estoy intentando de buscar la forma de como insertar un amigo a la lista del usuario logueado. Estoy trabajando con el framework de Django.

```
def add_as_friend(request, user_id):
if request.method == 'GET':
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['u_id'])
    friendship = Friendship.objects.get(id=user_id)
    friendship.friends_users.add(user)
    friendship.save()
    return redirect('/friends_list')
```

<---- viesw.py y models.py respectivamente ---->

```
class Friendship(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
friendship = models.ForeignKey(
    User, related_name="my_friend", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
friends_users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
objects = FriendshipManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name, self.friendship.user
```

<---- el error ---->
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

POR FAVOR NECESITO AYUDA, HE INTENTANDO TODA LA MAÑANA Y LA TARDE. (intente subir con el file.html que tengo pero por alguna razon extraña stackoverflow no me deja subirlo)

Comment: Obtienes algún error por consola??, que es lo que lo que pasa cuando tratas de añadirlo?? Por favor añade más detalles de tu problema. Lee [ask]

Comment: ahi esta amigo, edite la publicacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la línea del error `friendship = Friendship.objects.get(id=user_id)`
Le estas pasando el ID del usuario al ID de la tabla Friendship
según tu modelo debe ser:

```
friendship = Friendship.objects.get(friendship__id=user_id)
```

Lo que veo que necesitas es tomar la lista de amigos del usuario de la sesión `user` y agregar al `user_id` a la lista

```
user_sesion = User.objects.get(id=request.session['u_id'])
user_amigo = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
#buscar la lista de amigos de user_sesion
friendship_query = Friendship.objects.filter(friendship=user_sesion)
#asegurarse de que exista al menos una lista de amigos    
if len(friendship_query) > 0:
    #seleccionar la primera instancia
    friendship = friendship_query.first()
else:
    #como no existe la creo
    friendship = Friendship.objects.create(friendship=user_sesion)

friendship.friends_users.add(user)
friendship.save()
```

Para la consulta de Friendship hago un filter y luego tomo el primer elemento, esto pasa porque tienes una clave foránea que puede tener varios elementos, con el get da error cuando la consulta retorna más de una instancia.
Si deseas cambiar este comportamiento, considera cambiar la clave foránea a una relación de uno a uno `friendship = models.OneToOneField`, estarías diciendo que un usuario tiene una lista de amigos, actualmente tienes un usuario puede tener varias listas de amigos